# Debug Javascript application on chrome(android version) wirelessly (without usb debugging)

Tags: javascript, android, debugging, google-chrome, wireless

My android phone and my IIS are both connected to the same network. I wonder are there any ways that let me wirelessly debug javascript app which is running on android's chrome ?

Comment: run ur java script code in pc chrome test at there in android it will work

Comment: Read this, it might be what you are looking for: http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/remote-debug

Comment: @stackoverflow, PC version of chrome and Android version of chrome are not the same. Visit this [link](http://caniuse.com/#search=drag) as a sample

Comment: Is your device rooted? If so, you can use adb wireless to activate USB debugging without physically connecting your phone with your computer.

Comment: @TomTasche, my device is not rooted, would you explain more? thanks.

Comment: If you root your device and install an app like this (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rockolabs.adbkonnect) you can connect your phone over the network and debug it that way - just like if you plugged it into your computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using Weinre? http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/

There is also the option to use PhoneGap's working version of it for quickly trying out: http://debug.phonegap.com/

Comment: I've read about that "Weinre", I think this works. thanks @gauntFace